# Double Summation over a Subset of a Cartesian Product

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

From the "Probability & Statistical Inference, 9th edition" by Hogg, Tannis, Zimmerman, it is stated that one of the properties of the **Joint Probability Mass Function of Random Variables $X_1$ and $X_2$** is

$$P[(X_1,X_2)\in A] = \sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in A}\sum p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(x_1,x_2);\quad\text{   where $A \subseteq \Omega_{_{X_1,X_2}}$ $\quad$ . . . $\quad$ (1)}$$

My question basically is if I have, say $A=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}$, then how exactly do I index the summation in the form
$$ \sum_{x_1}\sum_{x_2} p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(x_1,x_2) $$

Moreover, if the summation in $(1)$  is intended to be
$$ \sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in A}\sum p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(x_1,x_2) =  p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(1,1)+p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(1,2)+p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(2,2); \quad\text{ where $A = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\}$} $$
then shouldn't the summation be written as
$$\sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in A}p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(x_1,x_2) \quad\text {instead of as the summation in $\quad (1)$}$$

[Note: I'm not very well versed in the rules of summation outside of Wikipedia, hence I would really appreciate it if someone could recommend some books/notes on this topic. ]

Comment: Imho: their second $\sum$ in their (1) is gratuitous. Your version of (1) looks better. Does not matter much. It is pretty clear what that summation should be (you spelled it out in that concrete example).

Comment: @KurtG. Thank you very much for your input!
I have a question though, is there any "formal" definition/meaning to the notation $$\sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in A}\sum p_{_{X_1,X_2}}(x_1,x_2)$$ 
or it is merely a convention/abuse of notation that is being used here by the author(s)? Because from my understanding of how double summation works, I can't seem to make sense out of how such notation implies the notion as per my example.

Comment: Finding good notation is an art, not a formal science. Some people like to write $\iint$ vs. $\int$ when the region of integration is not one dimensional. Perhaps that was what those authors had in mind. Calling it an abuse of notation that does not make sense goes far over the top.

Comment: @KurtG. Ahh I see. I get it now. Great analogy btw using the double integral. Thank you very much again for your input!